# How to get windows 11-like pinch gestures on kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, libinput, gestures

I am using a dual booted setup of windows 11 and kubuntu. Unfortunately, kubuntu doesn't support the pinch gestures out of the box which were very useful. So I installed libinput gestures for it but for some reason its not working. All my dependencies are installed(including the GUI gestures which I realize is not a dependency).
Here's a snippet from my /etc/libinput-gestures.conf file:

```
# KDE Plasma open/close overview
gesture pinch in       xdotool key ctrl+F9
gesture pinch out      xdotool key ctrl+F9
```

For some reason this is not working even after restarting libinput-gestures-setup.
Is there something I am missing here?
Also I don't fully know that whether these mappings will give me smooth pinch gestures like that of windows 11. Can anyone suggest any solutions to emulate that behavior?

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
```

Comment: I have not used Windows 11, so what exactly do you want to achieve with the pinching gestures? Do you want to zoom in/out in your browser? In that case, which browser are you using?

Comment: Also, run the command `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` and post the output by editing your question (the edit link is below your question)

Comment: Basically yes, I am trying to zoom in/out in my browser but not the regular ctrl+/ctrl- zoom that responsive pages react to but rather something similar to windows 11(or macOS) where you can just zoom in without having the pages react. I use the Microsoft-edge browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the Plasma Wayland Session

```
sudo apt install plasma-workspace-wayland
```

Restart the computer and choose the `Plasma (Wayland)` session (not the `Plasma (X11)` session) in the login screen.

Afterwards,run Microsoft Edge with the command

```
microsoft-edge --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland
```

Now it should support pinch gestures.

I am unsure if that enables wayland permanently in MS Edge. If it does not work when you launch the browser from the app menu, you will have to [modify](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application) the microsoft edge desktop file with these flags and place it in `$HOME/.local/share/applications`. Let us know if you need further help regarding this.

Comment: Ok I switched to wayland and the pinch gestures work as intended but the new issue is that everything is tiny now. Except for my panel, (which remained the same size), every application and their texts have shrunk in size to the point of being unreadable. Adjusting the fonts doesn't seem to solve the issue and I don't know whether I should mess with the scale option.
Should I make a separate question regarding this issue?

Comment: Open display settings and apply a suitable fractional scaling

Comment: Is there any way to use the same gestures on x11 instead of wayland?

Comment: For x11 there is an app called touchegg https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg. It supports gestures for Firefox and Chrome under x11. I am not sure about Edge. Since edge is chromium based, it may work. If you have questions, please open an issue at the github repo

Comment: By the way, did fractional scaling in Wayland not work?

Comment: Fractional scaling worked out. I was just curious. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You can accept my answer if it works for you, by clicking on the checkmark. Also, you may have to manually enable tap to click in Wayland once again

Comment: Yes I already manually enabled it and thanks for telling me about the acceptance of answer. I'm still new to stack exchange.