How How do I create an icon button
I recently installed Seamonkey unto Ubuntu 24.04 and want to create an icon for it. How do I do that?
Please give clear instructions because I am new to using Linux.
Thank you.

You will have to create a .desktop file, and place it in $HOME/.local/share/applications. https://askubuntu.com/q/281293/124466

Does this answer your question? Creating a .desktop file for a new application
