# How to install Aptana

Tags: aptana-studio

I downloaded Aptana stand alone version. Now I am on Ubuntu, but can not find any guide for installation. If you helped me, that would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you downloaded standalone version you can place Aptana Studio in whatever Folder you wish and invoke it by double clicking in the AptanaStudio3 icon as shown in the next screenshot:

[image]

Optionally you can move the extracted folder and it contents to your local programs folder `/usr/bin` via `gksudo nautilus` or via terminal but I think it is not needed unless you wish to invoke it via terminal.

If you wish to add an Application Icon to your Applications list from the Unity Launcher (or any other launcher like Synapse) you can simply create a `.desktop` file with the next contents on it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=AptanaStudio3
Comment=Aptana Studio 3
Exec=/home/geppettvs/Documents/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3
Icon=/home/geppettvs/Documents/Aptana_Studio_3/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

And place it inside of the ~/.local/share/applications/ folder. Remember to change the folder where AptanaStudio3 and its Icon resides in order to make it work properly.

Good luck!

Comment: Is there a way to run it from applications menu?

Comment: I added an edit for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install it, you can just unzip file and then execute the script named "ApantaStudio3".

Comment: Is there a way to run it from applications menu?

Comment: Sure.. check this out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/141229/how-to-add-a-shell-script-to-launcher-as-shortcut

Answer (score 0):

1) First, unzip aptana in your home directory.

2) Move the Aptana folder to /opt

```
sudo mv aptana /opt/
```

3) Create the desktop configuration file

```
sudo sublime aptana.desktop
```

...and paste this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Aptana Studio 3
Type=Application
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 aptana
Terminal=false
Icon=aptana
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Name[en]=Aptana Studio 3
```

4) Run this file:

```
sudo desktop-file-install aptana.desktop
```

5) Create symlink and copy icon:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/aptana/AptanaStudio3 /usr/local/bin/aptana
sudo cp /opt/aptana/icon.xpm /usr/share/pixmaps/aptana.xpm
```

6) Give the user the permissions of access to configuration settings:

```
sudo chown -R YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_USERNAME /opt/aptana/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi
```

N.B. The folder org.eclipse.osgi may not exist then it will create after the first Aptana launch.

If everything is done right then the Aptana icon will be available in Dash menu.