# Create desktop shortcut to log in as another user

Tags: login, gui, shortcuts

I'm trying to create a desktop shortcut (presumably to an executable script?) that will log into another specific user account on my system.

I want to log in to this other user's desktop GUI, ***not*** open a terminal prompt as them.

Comment: Does "Switch User" not do what you want?

Comment: I've created a shared user account just for steam big picture. I want a shortcut to Steam that won't prompt users to configure / log into steam within their user session.

Comment: The best response I've gotten on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/244qvm/can_i_create_a_desktop_shortcut_to_log_in_as/ch3zoeb) is to use `dm-tool switch-to-user USERNAME`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I can follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141229/how-to-add-a-shell-script-to-launcher-as-shortcut) using the code in my previous comment: `dm-tool switch-to-user USERNAME`