# Open up new terminal and run script with double click in Unity

Tags: command-line, scripts, sh

I want to execute

```
expect -c "
    spawn ssh user@10.0.0.0
    expect \"assword:\"
    send \"pass\r\"
    interact "
```

in a new terminal by doing double click in an .sh script.

I tried

```
#!/bin/bash

commands () {
    expect -c "
    spawn ssh root@10.0.0.0
    expect \"assword:\"
    send \"pass\r\"
    interact "
    $SHELL # keep the terminal open after the previous commands are executed
}

export -f commands

gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'commands'"
```

with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add shell script as shortcut](http://askubuntu.com/a/141247/295286)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a shell script to launcher as shortcut](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141229/how-to-add-a-shell-script-to-launcher-as-shortcut)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use gnome-terminal with the --disable-factory option that does:

   "Do not register with the activation name server, and do not reuse an already running GNOME terminal process"

   It will let the 'commands' environment variable through.

   gnome-terminal typically runs in a server mode. First launch starts a process, next launches send messages to main process to open a new window. So, env vars are set only on the first launch.
2. You can use a separate script file and pass its file name to bash. Or make it clever: detect inside this script its actual file name and pass it to bash, so it'll call this same script inside the gnome-terminal (but pass a parameter to take a different code path).
3. You can stuff everything into a variable, but make sure that it expands before the call to the gnome-terminal.