# Don't run terminal when I click a new launcher

Tags: launcher

I am trying to launch teamspeak from an icon in the launcher. I followed this guide [How to add a shell script to launcher as shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141229/how-to-add-a-shell-script-to-launcher-as-shortcut)
. The launcher works fine. My gripe is that it still opens a shell. When I try and open the other applications on the launcher, it does not open any terminals. I can't understand why. How do I stop the shell opening, or have I just implemented it wrong?

Separate to the main issue, where can I find icon's that I can use on the launcher side panel? And does it matter what size they are, or does Linux scale the image to size when you drag it onto the launcher?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=unmount-mount
Icon=/usr/bin/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/Dakirby309-Simply-Styled-TeamSpeak.i‌​co
Exec=/usr/bin/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh
```

Comment: The question (and answer) about the icon should really be a different question; they're great (and apply to more than teamspeak), but they're lost to future readers here.

Comment: @alexis http://askubuntu.com/questions/633028/how-can-i-make-an-icon-for-my-new-laucnher/633029#633029

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. We need to know what you've put in the `.desktop` file.

   Try editing the `Terminal=` line to be false:

   ```
   Terminal=false
   ```
2. I put all my icons in `/usr/share/icons` and I save them as a `.png` or a `.svg`. SVG is better (scalable), but can be a larger file size. Remember, this icon will be used for Alt+Tab switcher as well as the launcher and Dash search.

   ```
   Icon=/usr/share/icons/teamspeak.svg
   ```

   can be changed to just `teamspeak` **if** the icon is called `teamspeak.svg` (or `.png`) and is saved in `/usr/share/icons` (or the current folder for your icon pack).
3. Just made you an icon.

   [image]

   [Get the SVG here.](https://openclipart.org/detail/220211/teamspeak-logo)

   Linux will scale it for you.

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: If you like Tim's answer give him an upvote ^ , if he solved your problem, click grey checkmark to accept this answer. Thanks !

Comment: @Serg he can't upvote yet :)

Comment: because of 3 rep ? Well, no problem, other members of the community can upvote, but it's important to accept answers,though

Comment: Hi Tim,

Unfortunately nobody has told me how to format the code properly on my posts, so you will just have to look at the jumble of config below to see the config in the desktop file.

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=unmount-mount
Icon=/usr/bin/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/Dakirby309-Simply-Styled-TeamSpeak.ico
Exec=/usr/bin/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh

And hell yeah that works turning terminal to false.

Comment: @johnsmith okay, yes. You need to make the `terminal=true` line be `=false`, like in the answer here. The other things I suggested are up to you.

Comment: @johnsmith now you have enough reputation

Comment: @johnsmith if this is helpful, you can click the Tick, and / or the Upvote. I'm happy to keep helping if you still have issues with it though :)

Comment: Thanks Tim. I just have to ask, how did you get/make the icon? My primary worry is that I don't know how to get icons and/or if they will scale

Comment: @johnsmith I googled for the Teamspeak icon, and then made it in a free program called Inkscape. If you use the SVG file at this link: https://openclipart.org/detail/220211/teamspeak-logo Ubuntu will scale it automatically!

Comment: Ok great I will test it. It is only .SVG and .PNG files it scales? I think i used an .ico file or something when I added mine (never even heard of any of them except .png).

1 last thing (thanks for helping me btw), how can i paste lots of shell commands/code to this website and make it format my code correctly? I know you can do 4 spaces on each line, but I haven't nescessarily got time to indent large scripts with 4 spaces every time.

Comment: png doesn't scale. Only vector graphics files do, so for this, only svg will. To format it properly, select it all and press Ctrl+K, or click the `{}` button.

Comment: Hey, just tried highlighting and pressing ctrl K on the lines below, didn't work for me,

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=ts3
Icon=/usr/share/icons/ts.svg
Exec=/usr/bin/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh

Comment: It only works in question and answers, not comments.

Comment: @johnsmith, look [here](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) for information on how to compose text in this site. Also, while editing a question you can click the question mark on the top right to reveal a help menu.

Comment: Not sure why they don't just allow you to wrap stuff in <pre> </pre>. Would instantly fix the problem with pasting code on this site.

Comment: @johnsmith they do, but I edit it out. We use markdown which means you can read the contents easier before it is rendered - seeing something in 4 spaces makes it obvious what it is than keeping track of html tags

Comment: Ok. Tim would you be able to help me with something else? Nobody on the whole internet seems to be able to fix my problem (at least it feels that way right now).https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/38smv2/steam_doesnt_work_with_ubuntu_1504/