# How can I make an icon for my new launcher?

Tags: launcher, icons

I just created a new launcher, for teamspeak. This is the contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=unmount-mount
Icon=/usr/bin/TeamSpeak/TeamSpeak.i‌​co
Exec=/usr/bin/TeamSpeak/runscript.sh
```

How can I create an icon that will look good in both the launcher and the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> switcher, and the dash? How big does it have to be, and what format should I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First, the icon

Just made you one. <sup><sub>CC SA 3.0.</sub></sup>

[image]

Adapted from [aleixoteixeira](http://rocketdock.com/user/40878)'s design.

[Get the SVG here](https://openclipart.org/detail/220211/teamspeak-logo) - ubuntu will scale it and it will never be blury because it's an SVG file.

### What to do with it now?

I save all my icons in either `/usr/share/icons/` or `/usr/share/icons/current_pack`. It makes no difference, and I don't know what is better practise.

`png` will scale, but when it tries to scale it bigger will look blurry. Only vector graphics files do, so for this `svg` is best.