# Why does launching my own script from a launcher only work once?

Tags: unity, scripts, launcher, window, .desktop

I created a shell script, let's say it's

```
echo hi
sleep 5
echo bye
exit
```

Then I created a `.desktop` -file to launch the shell script. Double-clicking it works perfectly fine:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Test
Comment=Bash Cript
Exec=bash /example/test.sh
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

After drag- and dropping the .desktop-File into the Unity Launcher, I can click on it. **ONCE.**
After the first launch, the icon stays in the launcher, but clicking on it doesn't do anything.

Middle-Mouse clicking on it launches the application again

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you create the `.desktop` file as described [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141229/how-to-add-a-shell-script-to-launcher-as-shortcut) ? Did you add the `Type=Application` and possibly `Terminal=true` bits ? Maybe Unity needs them.

Comment: I did.I just edited my post and added my Desktop Entry.

Comment: Hi @Alex could you mention if you managed?

Answer (score 5):

#### It *does* work

...even tested it, but the launcher icon is unresponsive for about 7 seconds after you clicked. If you click again after these 7 seconds, it will work again.

This "break" is caused by the icon, waiting for a window to appear. This won' t be the case, since the appearing `gnome-terminal` -window is "claimed" by the `gnome-terminal`'s launcher icon, and your "home-made" icon does not recognize the window as "his".

#### Solution?

You *could* solve the issue by adding a line to your launcher (14.04)

```
StartupWMClass=gnome-terminal
```

or (16.04):

```
StartupWMClass=gnome-terminal-server
```

*however*, only do this for reasons of testing, *don't* use this as a permanent solution; having mutiple `.desktop` files, possibly claiming the same `WM_CLASS` in their main command is a bad idea, it will cause clashes in how `gnome-terminal` appears in the Unity launcher.

#### Better solution

Better add your script as a right-click option to the existing `gnome-terminal` launcher:

[image]

1. Copy the global `gnome-terminal` launcher from `/usr/share/applications` to

`~/.local/share/applications`:

```
    cp /usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

2. Open the file with `gedit`:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop
   ```
3. Change the line:

   ```
   Actions=New;
   ```

   into:

   ```
   Actions=New;My Script;
   ```

   and add the section:

   ```
   [Desktop Action My Script]
   Name=My Script
   Exec=gnome-terminal -e "bash /absolute/path/to/your/script.sh"
   ```

   to the very end of the file. Then log out and back in, and you'll have your script available as a quicklist- shortcut in the `gnome-terminal` launcher.

Comment: I cannot agree on the "if you click again after 7 seconds"-part.

Adding "StartupWMClass=gnome-terminal" does not seem to change anything.

Anyway: Adding the script as a seperate action is working. But that's not  what i'm looking for, as i want to be able to define an icon.

Comment: @Alex You didn't mention your Ubuntu version.If it is 16.04, it should be `gnome-terminal-server`, as mentioned, that is a bad solution however.