# Can I start an application with a specific nice value from its launcher?

Tags: command-line, unity, launcher, .desktop, nice

Is there a way to get a program (i.e. Firefox) to execute with the *nice* command from the Launcher ("nice firefox")? Saw one (1) post elsewhere saying you could right-click the Launch icon and select "Edit command," but mine do not seem to have that option. (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Comment: It's certainly possible to edit those launcher files but its not recommended. There's a couple alternative ways that i can think of, for example via top panel indicator, but i don't see a unity launcher solution.

Comment: Another alternative would be via the CLI as in `nice -10  /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome ` or `nice -10  firefox` (If the executable isn't on your path you need to provide it in full.)

Comment: @Elder Geek:  ...Which begs another question: Can you start shell scripts from Launch? (I have no aversion to using the CLI, just looking for alternatives using Launch.)

Comment: @NathanH Of course! http://askubuntu.com/questions/141229/how-to-add-a-shell-script-to-launcher-as-shortcut

Comment: Thanks for all the responses; appreciate the help. Flag this one "complete."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Imo the best way to do that is adding a right- click (quicklist) entry to the firefox launcher. There are a few options:

#### 1. Manually

1. copy the firefox launcher from `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications`

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Open the file with (e.g.) gedit, Look for the line starting with:

   ```
   Actions=
   ```

   Add "Nice firefox" to the line:

   ```
   Actions=NewWindow;Nice firefox;
   ```

   Add to the very bottom of the file a section:

   ```
   [Desktop Action Nice firefox]
   Name=Nice firefox
   Exec=nice -10 firefox
   ```
3. Now save the file, log out and back in. A new entry appears:

   [image]

#### 2. Use a GUI quicklist editor

...like [this one](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/qle-unity-quicklist-editor-20-released.html)

[image]

After installing, open the editor, choose the firefox launcher from the list (no need to say it needs to be locked to the launcher), and click the big **+** to add your entry.

*To install:*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vlijm/qle
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qle
```