# Executable shell script doesn't run

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, executable

I followed https://askubuntu.com/a/141247/638554 to create an executable script to add to my launcher. When I run `my_script.sh` it opens the program, but when I double click the executable I created in `/usr/shared/applications`, it doesn't open the program. It shows the app icon in the launcher for like 3-4 seconds, and then quits.

When I check the executable's properties, it shows the same `/path/to/shell/my_script.sh` as Command

This is my file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=Robo3T
Icon=/path/to/file/robo3t/robo3t.png
Exec=/path/to/file/robo3t/start.sh
```

[image]

Comment: try `sh /home/burn/Documents/robo3t/start.sh` instead.

Comment: Did you make it executable?

Comment: can you please clarify what you are doing exactly. I can not follow . First, if this application/script is outside the repos I highly suggest your place the .desktop in /usr/local/share/applications/ . Second I can not tell where your application lives as you are using variables. At one point you use `/home/burn/Documenta/robo3t/start.sh` , but then you use `/path/to/shell/my_script.sh` and `/path/to/file/robo3t/start.sh`

Comment: If you want the application to be available to all users, put things in system directories. If it is for just yo , use `/home/myusername/.local/share/applications`

Comment: Put your script in `~/bin` and on

Comment: And finally, post your script.