# How to solve the problem of untrusted application launcher in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, .desktop

[image]I installed mahasecure app from bank of maharastra internet banking site. I am new to ubuntu and was using windows all these years. Somehow, I managed to install it reading the suggestions provided in the discussion form. However, I get error message as attached. Please help. I am not a coder, please suggest the solution.

[image: The second image show the properties of file]

Comment: Try typing in a terminal (without quotes) "sudo ~/Desktop/MahaSecure.desktop" it will prompt you for a password, it should be the one you use to login to the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the launcher icon (`MahaSecure.desktop` file as per your screenshot) and select *Properties*. Then go to the *Permissions* tab and check the "*Allow executing file as program*" option.

Then double-click on the launcher icon. It may ask you to "*trust and launch*". Do it.

Comment: The "Allow executing file as program" is already checked. It is also showing that owner and group as root.  Also at the bottom it is showing "you are not the owner so you cannot change these permissions".

Comment: @Syam Run this command in Terminal: `cp ~/Desktop/MahaSecure.desktop ~/Desktop/maha-secure.desktop`. You should see another file called `maha-secure.desktop` in your desktop. Follow the steps from the answer with this new file.

Comment: Thanks, the icon starts visible. However, double clicking on the icon is irresponsive.

Comment: Then most likely something is wrong with the content of the launcher.

Comment: Same is happening to me.  It begun with a crash, all desktop icons position and images were lost, executables begun asking por "trust and launch" every single time.  They have execute permission.

Comment: @YoArgentino Consider placing the `.desktop` launchers in your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory so that you'll be launch the applications easily from "Activities" overview.

Comment: This worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056591/how-to-mark-desktop-file-as-trusted-in-18-04

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER $HOME/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I did:

```bash
sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/Desktop/desktopfile
```

This worked for me as well.

That changed the ownership from what it was to me (the current logged-in user).

After the `chown`, I still got the error, but had a second option to Accept and Trust.