# Openshot app not visible anywhere

Tags: openshot

I have downloaded openshot from terminal as stated on a website like this:-

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openshot.developers/ppa

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install openshot-qt
```

I didn't see any error in the terminal while doing that. But i couldn't find the application anywhere.
Is this any other thing related to openshot; which can help me to usethat?
Help..

Comment: can just run `openshot` or `openshot-qt` from terminal or Alt-F2?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy openshot-qt` in Terminal.

Comment: Good ! So you're simply lacking the launcher. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/141229/631600) and maybe its duplicates or install and use `alacarte` to add a launcher

Answer (score 2):

As you said you can run openshot from terminal and from Run menu (Alt-F2), it seems you're simply lacking the launcher file to be able to open it from the menu.

Create an `openshot.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` (or `~/.local/share/applications` or directly in `~/Desktop`) with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Openshot
Exec=/usr/bin/openshot-qt
Icon=/path/to/openshot/icon
Type=Application
Categories=AudioVideo;
```

Make sure you have the correct path to the exec and to an icon.
Find icons below `/usr/share/icons/`

Alternatively you can use `alacarte` as GUI alternative to create launchers.

`sudo apt install alacarte`

Comment: that is why you need that launcher file

Comment: but it worked fine for openshot-qt

Comment: It adds an openshot-qt icon to the menu, so that you can access it as you normally would open any program (from the menu). Usually , the installation routines would do this for you.

Comment: That path `usr/share/icons/` has no icon of openshot