# Open an app on first login

Tags: login, autostart

I know Ubuntu supports autostart of apps every time a user logs in. But what I would like to do is to open a specific app every time a new user logs in for the first time and then the app won't autostart on any login. Is this possible?

Comment: I would try to do it via adding to a bash skel hack.  ie. when you create a new user it will grab the /etc/skel/ as it sets up the user account so its there. the .bash file on login would cause the app to start; then 'hack' (or just replace whole .bash_ file) removing the autorun starter.  hence on subsequent runs its no longer there....   (*this is a thought only; I've never had to do it so haven't thought it thru; hopefully there's a much better way!*)

Comment: Well, I am not much of a technical person, but it sounds like a plan. Would you tell me how to do it, or maybe post links to articles/questions that show how to implement it.

Comment: Do you create the new user account or do they create it?

Comment: I would create it

Comment: If you create the user account you can copy the `run-once.sh`  bash script (or whatever it is called) to the user home. What does the script do? Something like display a splash screen such as "Welcome to XYZ Corporation, Don't forget to make a new pot of coffee if you take the last cup"?

Comment: Where is `run-once.sh`? How do I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would suggest is a 2 step process:

1. Create a `myapp.desktop` file in  `/etc/skel/.config/` directory. Everything under `/etc/skel` gets copied to new users' folders when they get created.  For the format of that file, look into [How to add a shell script to launcher as shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/q/141229/295286). Don't worry about the title - the `.desktop` files are essentially same as Windows shortcuts, and their presence in user's `~/.config/autostart/` directory is what enables particular app to run upon GUI login.
2. Make the wrapper script that will run the app you want but then also remove the specific launcher, say for example

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   gedit
   rm ~/.config/autostart/myapp.desktop
   ```

   That way the autostart entry will run only on first login, and on that first login - remove itself. Potentially, you also may want to remove the script itself if necessary. Deleting is also not necessary, you could just rename it via `mv ~/.config/autostart/myapp.desktop ~/.config/autostart/myapp.desktop.bak`

Please note, that you didn't specify what particular app or what specific conditions you need for that app to work, so this is only a rough example, and feel free to adapt it to your needs.

On side note, a script may not even be necessary if what you wanna do is simple. For example, you may want to have the line as follows in your `.desktop` file:

```
Exec=bash -c 'firefox && rm ~/.config/autostart/myapp.desktop' myapp`
```

Comment: +1 have a run once script remove itself was along the lines of my thinking.

Comment: I get it. But I have a question. Why do I have to write "myapp" as the last word, in the last line `Exec=bash -c 'firefox && rm ~/.config/autostart/myapp.desktop' myapp\``. What if I don't have an app called myapp? I want to start firefox at login, Should I change myapp with firefox?

Comment: @LuciferConradReeves  When  `bash`, `ksh` or `/bin/sh` shells use the `-c` flag, the positional  parameter specified on the command gets assigned into `$0` variable, which normally holds the shell or script name. This is not so much a requirement as a good practice in this case. So you can place almost anything there instead.    If you are writing a command that does involve processing positional parameters, then you have to place something there, otherwise you'll be confused as to why the shell doesn't process the very first item :)

Comment: I just want to launch firefox, nothing else. What should I write there? I am still unable to get you. (I am nothing more than a newbie)

Comment: @LuciferConradReeves  Just write `Exec=bash -c 'firefox && rm ~/.config/autostart/myapp.desktop'` Don't worry about the positional parameters.  Did you read the linked answer about creating `.desktop` files ?

Comment: @LuciferConradReeves You're welcome. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible. I have and idea but maybe there are better solutions too, here is my idea hope it help ;)

if you know a little about `shell` programing language or `python` or ... you can make a script that whenever you run this script, it get your username and `create a text file/a row in database/ a row in a file` and before this step, it checked already if this username had been in the database file or not, if not, then it runs your program and if yes, it don't. the python code can be like this (save it as Runit.py) :

```
import sys
import getpass
import os

def createFile():
    f = open("usersFirstLogin.txt", "a+")
    f.write(user)
    f.close()
    os.system("echo Hi") # Run YOUR PROGRAM HERE
    return 0
user = getpass.getuser()
fr = open("usersFirstLogin.txt", "a+")
count=0
for x in fr:
    if(x == user):      
        count+=1            
        continue # DO NOTHING HERE
    else:           
        createFile()
        count+=1
if (count == 0):
    createFile()
fr.close
```

but now, how we can set this to run at the start? it's easy with systemd. suppose we make this python script with name `Runit.py` we need to :

```
sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/RunMyScript.service
```

then with

```
sudo gedit /etc/systemd/system/RunMyScript.service
```

type these in it :

```
[Unit]
Description=RunIt

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/Path/to/the/Runit.py folder
ExecStart=/Path/to/the/Runit.py folder/Runit.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

now your service is ready for start at login :

```
sudo systemctl enable RunMyScript.service
```

in this scenario your service always run for each login and your script check whether if for that user already ran or not.

Comment: Wait, how's this even useful to me? I don't know shell programming or python. For example, I would like to start firefox every time a new user logs in, but implementing this would certainly not start it. Plus I also don't understand more than half of your answer.

Comment: I wrote the python code for you, I just run it and it works, you need to change the line `os.system("echo Hi") # Run YOUR PROGRAM HERE` so that instead of `echo Hi` you need to put your specific command for example /usr/bin/firefox, sorry if it's not clear, please tell me where you have problem ?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't work. I don't understand half of the terms