# File Extension For Shell Execute

Tags: bash, scripts, nautilus, executable

I have the allowed execution of shell scripts (they were already X by default in properties) but can not run them from outside the terminal without opening them to edit. I scrolled down in 'open with other app' and tried "run software", no luck. Can I execute files from the desktop?

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu/Linux so called file extension doesn't play a role to the file execution. It depends of the file [permissions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes). For example, the command  `chmod +x filename` will allow the execution of the file by all - owner/**u**ser, **g**roup and **o**thers. Or by using `chmod u+x filename` the executable permission will be granted only to the user/owner.

Within the desktop environment the behaviour of the executable files depends on the settings of your primary file manager. For example within Ubuntu 16.04 this is Nautilus. To change the behaviour: Open Nautilus; go to Edit menu and choice Preferences. Then click on the Behaviour tab. There are three options of the behaviour of the Executable Text Files:

[image]

Another way to execute a file within the desktop environment (while the option *View executable text files when they are opened* is selected) is to create dedicated `.desktop` [launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141229/how-to-add-a-shell-script-to-launcher-as-shortcut) for that file.

Comment: I seem to have lost the edit (files) menu, which I recall was previously standard. Probably this is related to gnome tweaks or user themes. Sorry, I had been warned those can break things. Suppose I'll look at that, though it might be faster to just reinstall the os

Comment: @DDPenga, I think you do not need to reinstall the OS, you can create another user with administrative (root/sudo) rights. All these tweaks are for the current user... so the easiest way is to (rename the current user and) create new user, copy your personal files, etc... but do not copy `.config/` and `.local/` dirs... Then you can remove the old user and its home directory...

Comment: @DDPenga, whether the Edit menu is really lost? This could help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RxPENk6rlVU

Comment: I had moved the files menu location by experimentation with themes. Thanks for the link and the suggestion that I can make another user if I need to. This post was really bad of me. Ethereal system. I raged at it

Comment: er, Vulkan, Mesa, AMD, like