# Creating desktop launcher for jupyter-notebook, but it is inside a python virtual environment

Tags: command-line, bash, python, .desktop, jupyter

Like many other developers, I always follow this routine when I want to launch the jupyter notebooks that run in my repository (with a pipenv virtual environment):

```
cd /path/to/your/repository
pipenv shell (or conda activate, or other virtualenvs)
jupyter-notebook
```

But this is a pain in the ass. I would like to have a desktop application that did this automatically and so I follow [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141229/how-to-add-a-shell-script-to-launcher-as-shortcut).

The code that I put in the shell script for the launcher is exactly the routine that I do every day (the same that is above this lines).

But when I want to

```
source jupyterlauncher.sh
```

, the terminal gets stuck just after the environment activation! It is just as if ubuntu created a brand new terminal after that line.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `jupyter-notebook` command gets attached to the terminal, you need to send it to the background, just add an ampersand `&` to the end of the line, like this:

```
jupyter-notebook &
```

Remember that now you need to quit the server from the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

That can be done by creating a .desktop (like jupyter.desktop) file. The file content can be like...

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Jupyter Notebook
Exec=bash -c 'cd /path/to/repository;source /path/to/venv/bin/activate;jupyter-notebook'
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=true 
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

```
"/path/to/reository" should be where you want to open the jupyter notebook
"source /path/to/venv/bin/activate" is the virtual environment activation command. Change this according to your virtual environment
```