# drag and drop to launcher doesn't work

Tags: unity, launcher

based on this [How to add a shell script to launcher as shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141229/how-to-add-a-shell-script-to-launcher-as-shortcut) I moved a `.desktop` file to the `.local\share\applications`. Anyway, in the rest it tells that I must drag and drop it to the launcher. But it doesn't respond or open a new location in the launcher so I put it there. It just doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is the correct way, but I found this simple solution:

- Run your desktop file from terminal
- As it opens, a launcher entry is shown
- Move this entry up or down and the launcher let you to put it there permanently