# How do I add links to launcher

Tags: launcher, symbolic-link

I am new to Ubuntu; I've been using it for a couple hours now, and I encountered one little problem that I was hoping to solve. I got a program on my computer without actually using the software center or packages, it's just a folder with a executable file in it. So I figured that it's not a problem and just put the folder in a safe place and created a link to the executable file which I put on the desktop.

So here's the question: how do I get the link into the launcher?

Answer (score 6):

Either of these would solve your issue:

[How can I add a bash script to the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76342/how-can-i-add-a-bash-script-to-the-unity-launcher)

[How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)

Basically, you need an icon (**.desktop**) file than be docked to the Unity bar (left of screen).