# How can I install Celtx 2.9.7 properly on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, lts, install-from-source

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux and I want to install and use the newest version of the screenwriting software **[Celtx](http://www.celtx.com)** on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

After trying https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+question/206295 and using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dreamstudio/video
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install celtx
```

I unfortunately had to find out that was a rather old version with a fairly screwed up UI. I then downloaded the newest version from http://download.celtx.com/2.9.7/Celtx-2.9.7-64.tar.bz2 but now I don't know how to properly install it.

I extracted it to /home/username/ (there was no ~/bin/) as described **[here](http://wiki.celtx.com/index.php?title=Installation#For_Linux)** and I can now launch the application by running the file *celtx* within that folder (I get asked whether I want to Display, run or run it in Terminal) and it works fine. But I can't get it to launch from Unity.

I tried right-clicking the launcher button and going "Lock to Launcher" while it's running and it does create an icon but clicking it to launch the program does nothing. Also searching for celtx in the Dash doesn't find the app.

And advice on how to properly install Celtx 2.9.7 in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Comment: to lock to unity you can use this http://askubuntu.com/questions/76342/how-can-i-add-a-bash-script-to-the-unity-launcher

Comment: Was having the same trouble and [this](http://ubuntu.philipcasey.com/installing-celtx-in-ubuntu/) pretty much fixed it. Its more of a patch than an install but I'm having no problems with it on ChrUbuntu. Hope that works!

Comment: This is untested, but I found [a link that describes how to do it](http://ubuntu.philipcasey.com/installing-celtx-in-ubuntu/). I'm going to try it myself in a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial: [How to Install Celtx 2.9.7 on Ubuntu Linux](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/install-celtx-2-9-7-ubuntu-linux/) might help people in the future, as I found it very brief and clear. Just pay attention to your download path: If your Celtx install archive is not in the default Downloads folder, type it in manually.

1. Press Ctrl+Alt+T to open the terminal, then run the below commands one by one to extract to `/usr/local/`:

   ```
   cd  
   tar xjf ~/Downloads/Celtx-*.tar.bz2
   sudo mv ~/celtx/ /usr/local/
   ```
2. Now create a shortcut launcher for Celtx:

   Install required package:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install gnome-panel --no-install-recommends
   ```

   Run this command to create a launcher for Celtx:

   ```
   sudo gnome-desktop-item-edit /usr/share/applications/ --create-new
   ```

   Select icon from `/usr/local/celtx/icons/` folder. Type `/usr/local/celtx/celtx` in command area.

Now you can search for and open celtx in the Unity Dash.

Answer (score 0):

Using your terminal, just put the extracted `celtx` folder in `/usr/lib`. You may need root permission. So go to where you extracted the folder and just type

`sudo mv celtx /usr/lib`

Then, `cd` to `/usr/lib/celtx`. Type `./celtx` and it will launch.

You can create a launcher to do it in the future. Just remember that most program folders, when you look inside and see a bunch of files ending in `.so` or whatever, go into `/usr/lib`.