# linking to an executable with options

Tags: shortcuts, symbolic-link

I want to have a link to an executable as follows, the equivalent terminal command is:

```
Mathematica -mesa
```

The command `ln -s Mathematica -mesa Mathematica` does not work, how can I include `-mesa` in the link?

Thanks,
Woody

Comment: do you want this to work from the command line, or are you looking for a desktop or launcher shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

Mathematica -mesa
```

Don't forget to make the script executable and store it in the `$PATH`.

Comment: That worked to create the 'link' but I then found that I couldn't add it to the launcher which I didn't mention in my post, this post eventually solved my problem. http://askubuntu.com/questions/76342/how-can-i-add-a-bash-script-to-the-unity-launcher

Thank you for help.

Comment: It must be possible to add a given script to a launcher. I can do it in KDE (I'm on Kubuntu).