# How to install the Jason plugin for jEdit?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, scripts, plugins, text-editor

I am a newbie in Ubuntu (14.04) so I am very appreciative if you can guide me how to install Jason as a plugin of jEdit.

[Jason installation homepage](http://jason.sourceforge.net/mini-tutorial/getting-started/).

[jEdit plugin installation instructions](http://plugins.jedit.org/install.php).

The Jason page makes it sound very easy by just `run bin/jason.sh`. I tried to do this in a terminal but `run` command was not found and I don't know what package I should install. If I double clicked on `jason.sh`, this file will be opened in jEdit but nothing happen.

Nor I tried to install Jason manually by copy the source file into `usr/share/jEdit/jars` but it didn't work neither.

Updated with screenshot:

[image]

It looks like I haven't permission to execute this file in this folder. I tried to do again with `sudo` but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The installation instructions](http://jason.sourceforge.net/mini-tutorial/getting-started/getting-started.html#SECTION00020000000000000000) aren't telling you to run `run bin/jason.sh`. They're saying to run `bin/jason.sh`.

Suppose you wanted to put the `Jason` folder in your home folder:

```
cd # changes to your home folder

# change URL for different version or different mirror
wget http://superb-dca3.dl.sourceforge.net/project/jason/jason/version%201.4.1/Jason-1.4.1.tgz  

tar xf Jason-1.4.1.tgz

cd Jason-1.4.1
```

Either or both of those steps can be performed with the GUI (via a web browser and archive manager). If you did it that way, then to continue, type `cd` followed by a space, drag the `Jason-1.4.1` folder into the Terminal to paste its full path (the version number may be different, if you're reading this in the future), then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

A couple notes about permissions and privileges:

- The Jason archive you download contains files whose permissions have to be set a certain way in order for Jason to run properly (or, in some cases, at all). It appears, based on some of the information you've recently provided, that `jason.sh` is not set as executable.

  *Maybe you downloaded the .zip file instead of the .tgz.* A .zip archive does not typically preserve executable and other Unix-style permissions. As there are many more files than just `jason.sh` that rely on having the correct permissions, the correct solution is to start over using the `.tgz` file. This is one of the options when you download Jason.
  <sub>[31 other files](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8509758/) in the archive are supposed to be marked executable, which is why just setting the permissions for that one file is probably not the best fix, even if you are able to do so. Several of those other files are also scripts or programs and thus clearly do need those permissions. (For some it seems odd they're +x, but it's not applied indiscriminately--other files in the same dirs with the same suffixes are -x.)</sub>

  Or: *Maybe the drive you've extracted the .tgz archive to is **an NTFS or FAT32 drive**, or some other drive that doesn't support Unix-style permissions.* Then every file will have the default permissions for files and every folder will have the default permissions for folders, set when that filesystem was mounted. You can change those defaults, but you probably shouldn't--then you'd have all sorts of files marked executable that *aren't* supposed to be. Instead, **extract `Jason-1.4.1.tgz` somewhere like your home folder** where Unix-style permissions are supported.

  Or: *Maybe the drive you've extracted the .tgz archive to is mounted with the noexec option.* This is the least likely (especially based on the information you've since provided), since permissions can still be changed on noexec filesystems, the files on them just can't be run as executables. But if this is the case, the solution is the same--move the archive somewhere else and extract it there.
- Assuming you're putting Jason in your home folder as above, this copy should belong to your user. You don't need to--and shouldn't--perform any action as root (with `sudo` or otherwise) as part of the installation. *You also almost certainly should not run Jason as root (even if you did install it systemwide).*

Now that you're in the `Jason-1.4.1` folder, run the `jason.sh` script located in the `bin` subfolder by issuing the command:

```
bin/jason.sh
```

Provided you have all the required dependencies (e.g., Java), it should run Jason.

This is good for verifying Jason works, but most of the time you'll probably want to run it from the GUI. There's two main ways.

You can make make it so Nautilus will run shell scripts (provided they're marked executable) when you double-click on them:

- [How do I run executable scripts in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus)

Or you can create a launcher to run the script:

- [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)
- [How to add a shell script to launcher as shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141229/how-to-add-a-shell-script-to-launcher-as-shortcut)
- [How can I add a bash script to the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76342/how-can-i-add-a-bash-script-to-the-unity-launcher)
- [How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)

You'll probably want to make a launcher. For convenience, here's one way to do that.

This is based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/30530/22949) and [that one](https://askubuntu.com/a/66918/22949). (If you're using the MATE desktop environment, use `mate-desktop-item-edit` in place of `gnome-desktop-item-edit`.)

1. Right-click on your desktop and click *Create Launcher...* or, if you don't have that option, run `gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop`.
2. For Type, keep Application.
3. For Name, put `Jason` (or whatever you like).
4. For command, enter the fully qualified path to `jason.sh` or browse for it (with the Browse... button). Mine is `/home/ek/Jason-1.4.1/bin/jason.sh`. If you're using the same version of Jason and you followed the instructions above, just replace `ek` with your own username.

   [image: image of Create Launcher dialog box, making a launcher for jason.sh]

   If you're in the Terminal where you ran `bin/jason.sh` successfully, running `readlink -f bin/jason.sh` will reveal the full path:

   ```
   ek@Ilex:~/Jason-1.4.1$ readlink -f bin/jason.sh
   /home/ek/Jason-1.4.1/bin/jason.sh
   ```
5. Click OK.
6. Now you have a desktop launcher called Jason that you can double-click to start the application easily. (You can move this somewhere other than your desktop, if you like.)

   [image]

Comment: I tried to run `./bin/jason.sh` from the terminal but it didn't work,it said `command not found`.But now I am away from my laptop,I'll try yours later,thank

Comment: @Tuong What directory were you in when you ran that command?

Comment: I remembered that I run it from its extract folder Jason-1.4.1,but I am not so sure about this.I just remmember that I tried to run `jason.sh` only and the terminal said the command not found

Comment: @Tuong When you regain access to the computer where the error is happening, please let me know where `jason.sh` is (if you can) and where you are when you run the command `bin/jason.sh` (or `./bin/jason.sh` which should also work, but the leading `./` is unnecessary since `bin/jason.sh` already contains a `/` and will thus be interpreted as the path to a specific executable).

Comment: I'll update the question with images later,thank a lot

Comment: I updated with the screenshot, my problem here is permission, do I need to do anything else.

Comment: @Tuong I recommend copying text from the terminal (select, press Ctrl+Shift+C) and pasting it in your question, not using an image for something text-based. While editing, select text and press Ctrl+K (or click the `<$>` tool) so it appears as code. I suspect you're right that it's a permissions problem on `jason.sh`. (Btw, though this isn't the cause, you almost certainly shouldn't be using `sudo` to run Jason.) ...What is the exact name of the file you downloaded? If you used the .zip file instead of the .tgz file that may explain the problem. The .tgz should unpack with correct permissions.

Comment: @EliahKagan: +1 for the launcher, I like the step by step instructions.

Comment: @EliahKagan next time I will copy text only, thank a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `Jason-1.3.9/bin` folder :

Run command `sh jason.sh`

Answer (score 0):

After decompressing the Jason archive, the command to type is `bin/jason.sh` NOT `run bin/jason.sh`:

```
sylvain@sylvain-ThinkPad-T430s:~/Downloads/Jason-1.4.1$ chmod +x bin/jason.sh
sylvain@sylvain-ThinkPad-T430s:~/Downloads/Jason-1.4.1$ bash bin/jason.sh 
JDK_HOME is not properly set!
sylvain@sylvain-ThinkPad-T430s:~/Downloads/Jason-1.4.1$
```

[image]

Comment: It's not worked for me

Comment: @Tuong: I've updated my answer with a preliminary step to ensure the script has the right persmission (`+x` means executable)

Comment: It still not worked,I checked the `jason.sh` but in `Properties->Permissions` the checkbox `Allow executing file as program` is still not checked, whenever I tried to check it, it would be unchecked automatically

Comment: @Tuong: Try my new proposal (`bash bin/jason.sh`).

Comment: It's worked.Sylvain Amazing! The only issue is the terminal showed a lot of errors like `[error] KillRing: /home/thovo/.jedit/killring.xml:1: unsupported XML version (found "1.1") (expected "1.0")` and `[error] PerspectiveManager:  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)` But can you explain the situation here for me?It would be a kind of experiences to deal with future issue. And if I exit the terminal, the Jason will quit also. Can you help me with this issue,Sylvain and Eliah?

Comment: @EliahKagan Good catch, I did not notice the path where Tuong uncompressed the archive. I'm 99% sure it's the root cause.

Comment: @Tuong Please download and extract the tar.gz instead as Eliah recommended (in your home directory). It should just work.

Comment: @Eliah You are correct, it looks like the problem, when I move the `.tgz` file to `Home->Desktop`,it is opened correctly just some error in terminal like this `JDK_HOME is not properly set!
[error] KillRing: /home/thovo/.jedit/killring.xml:1: unsupported XML version (found "1.1") (expected "1.0")` so I think I can just follow your instruction to add it to Launcher. This `/media/thovo/82B6B5E5B6B5D98B` is and NTFS drive. So if I want to put it in this directory, what should I do?
@Sylvain: I always use the `.tgz` file