# Locking keyboard, mouse and CDROM for baby

Tags: keyboard, lock

I use laptop and need to use keyboard between baby activities...

Is there any software for ubuntu that does all these things by pressing just one key (or predefined combination/password)?
I tried program lk4b but it does not locks CD and mouse, this is unsufficient for my baby...

Also how can i disable power button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keyboard "kid lock" software](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48391/keyboard-kid-lock-software)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can i disable power button?

You'll need hardware support for that. Or nice "there, I fixed it!" tape. A longer press on this button will inevitably power down the PC very roughly, no matter what OS you run on it or what program you try to have that prevent it.

For just ignoring the simple "hits" on it, go to your power settings and let it do nothing on pressing it:

[image]

Above screenshot is in KDE, but similar settings should be available in your Desktop Environment too (e.g. Unity, GNOME, ...) See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/66731/88802) for Unity.

> Locking keyboard, mouse

Have you tried setting a password to your screensaver? Or set up a custom shortcut to activate the screen locker (default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)?

> CDROM

Use

```
eject -i on
```

to lock the optical drive :)

Comment: Thank you, gertvdijk, but i cannot use screensaver and screenlocker with clr+alt+l, since i usually need baby lock while spoking via skype with baby's grandmother.... Sorry for initially uncorrect question...

Comment: Yeah, that's why I suggested setting up a custom keyboard shortcut, e.g. one of your unused media keys on your keyboard.

Comment: Mmmm... Again my incorrect behavior. Sorry. :) We using skype with video. Do you have a solution?

Comment: mateo_salta, thank you, but this is not my case. :) I use laptop and need to use keyboard between baby activities...

Comment: imagine what kind of explosion can do baby by touching so badly charged laptop! :) So i really need to lock it quickly with just few keypresses! :)

Comment: Disagree. Baby want to see grandmother on laptop screen (skype video call). There are many prorgams on windows for that purposes, why i cannot find analogue for ubuntu? :(

Comment: @AVIA Please mention some of these software products for Windows that provide this functionality, in your question.

Comment: gertvdijk, i used winkeylock and lockcd from sourceforge, and know that my friends use others. OK, i accept solution for CDROM, i agree that i not need to lock cdrom very often and quickly. I will use your solution for cdrom, possible with shortcut, thank you. But what can i do for power button and keyboard?

Comment: As I said in my answer. keyboard: lockscreen. Power button: hardware. But this can't be solved in any OS. Holding power button for several seconds will turn off the PC no matter what you run on it. This is hard coded in the BIOS/system board.

Comment: No, i asked not about holding power button! :) Baby cannot do this. Baby's presses are frequent and short, fast all babies do press keys in that manner. :) Can ubuntu disable power button like this is done in windows control panel (power settings)?

Comment: @AVIA Just added that use case :)

Comment: OK, thank you all. But universal all-in-one solution still welcome.

Comment: Guys!This is not a discussion forum. @AVIA Please include requested details in your question rather than posting comments. If you would prefer a single piece of software taking care of this, add the `software-recommendation` tag to your question as well. The downvote is because it's not a very good question in the current form, probably.